# When using subprocess.Popen to create tmux sessions is it possible to change the envionment variables for each new tmux session spawned from Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, tmux, torch

I'm trying to spawn multiple `tmux` sessions with different environment variables from the same python3 script.

I have been arguing `{**os.environ, "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":str(device_id)}` to the `env` key word argument to `subprocess.Popen`.

```
for device_id in device_ids:
    new_env = {**os.environ, "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":str(device_id)}
    p = subprocess.Popen([      
        'tmux', 'new', '-d', "-c", "./", '-s',                      
        sesh_name,                                                  
        "python3",                                                  
        path_to_script                                                    
    ], env=new_env)
```

I'm finding that the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES parameter, however, is equal to the first `device_id` that I argue across all processes. What is the meaning of this!?

Is this an inherent issue with Popen and the subprocess module? If so, how do I fix it?

I've tried to argue the device id to the script of the new process, but sadly torch won't allow me to update the environment variable after it's been imported and it would be way more trouble than it's worth to rework the code for that.

**EDIT: Providing minimal example**

Save this script as `test.py` (or whatever else you fancy):

```py
import subprocess                                                       
import os                                                               
                                                                        
def sesh(name):                                                         
    procs = []                                                          
    for device_id in [4,5,6]:                                           
        proc_env = {**os.environ, "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES": str(device_id)}          
        p = subprocess.Popen(['tmux', 'new', '-d', "-c", "./", '-s', name+str(device_id), "python3", "deleteme.py"], env=proc_env)
        procs.append(p)                                                 
    return procs                                                        
                                                                        
if __name__=="__main__":                                                
    sesh("foo")
```

Save this script as `deleteme.py` within the same directory:

```py
import time                                                             
import os                                                               
                                                                        
if __name__=="__main__":                                                
    print(os.environ)                                                   
    for i in range(11):                                                 
        print("running")                                                
        if "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" in os.environ:                        
            print(os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"])                   
        else:                                                           
            print("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES not found")                     
        time.sleep(5)
```

Then run `test.py` from the terminal.

```
$ python3 test.py
```

Then switch to the tmux sessions to figure out what environment is being created.

Comment: How is this working? `"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"=str(device_id)` should be `"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":str(device_id)`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: It should be working (assuming you fix the typo), I just tested something similar. I suspect something in the code you're running is overriding the environment variable.

Comment: My test: `for x in ["1", "2", "3"]: subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', 'echo "|$foo|"'], env={**os.environ, "foo": x})`

Comment: Yes, the equals sign was a copying error. Hmm, maybe it has something to do with the tmux sessions then. I print the `new_env` dict just before calling `subprocess.Popen` and the value is correct. But then I print `os.environ` in the script that I'm running from `Popen` and the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` value is consistently stuck on the first `device_id` I argued in the for loop.

Comment: Can you try calling individual tmux sessions in your setup?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] that can be run **without changes** to reproduce the problem. Needing to provide a `path_to_script` is a change.

Comment: Done, in the edits.

Comment: I would guess that one of the startup scripts being run by the shell that `tmux` launches is resetting that variable.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. I found a work around using `os.system` instead of `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @saetch_g Why does it matter what command I run in my test? I've proved that the environment variable is being passed differently in each call. Anything that happens to it after that is not a Python issue.

Comment: Because the issue I'm experiencing is still there regardless of if it's a python issue or not. But I should reword my question to make that clearer because the question is clearly focussed on `subprocess.Popen` which is python specific. So, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: I just changed the question to better reflect my issue.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else running into this problem, you can use `os.system` instead of `subprocess.Popen` in the following way.

```py
import os                                                                  
                                                                        
def sesh(name, device_id, script):                                                             
    command = "tmux new -d -s \"{}{}\" \'export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={}; python3 {} \'"
    command = command.format(                                              
        name,                                                           
        device_id,                                                      
        device_id,                                                         
        script                                                          
    )                                                                   
    os.system(command)                                                  
                                                                        
if __name__=="__main__":                                                
    sesh("foo", 4, "deleteme.py")
```

Comment: You can send that same `export` command using `subprocess.Popen()`. And you won't need to escape all the quotes.

Comment: You can apply this fix while still using `subprocess`. There's no legitimate reason to switch to `os.system()` -- invoking an extra shell introduces security bugs for no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: (if you want to use `os.system()` _without_ introducing security bugs, make sure you use `shlex.quote()` on each value you would otherwise inject with a format string)

Comment: Could one of you provide the formatting for doing this?